# How to get a pointer to each frame data during preview into Android Camera2 API?

Tags: android, c++, frame, preview, android-camera2

I'm trying to get the video frame data frame during an preview using camera2 API.
How do I get to pointer to each frame data.
Before displaying the frame preview on this site, send the frame data pointer together with a structure containing the video data format to a C ++ function (JNI native).
It's possible?
Please help me by giving me some suggestions?
I thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to get frames from preview in Java, you can add an `ImageReader` to your captures. Especially, you will need to impolement ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener [(doc here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener.html). From that ImageReader you can get raw bytes using code similar to that:

```
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener =
        new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image img = null;
                img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                Result rawResult = null;
                try {
                    if (img == null) throw new NullPointerException("cannot be null");
                    ByteBuffer buffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(data);

                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

                } catch (ReaderException ignored) {                        
                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                } finally {
                    mQrReader.reset();
                    if (img != null)
                        img.close();
                }
            }
};
```

You must create an `ImageReader`, and set its listener

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(...);
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, (...));
```

And you can add to your capture session in this way:

```
Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
Surface mImageSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();
mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageSurface);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
```

Please note that this is pseudocode to guide you, probably it's not ready to paste and work directly, but will provide you a good guide on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks webo, I did the method which capture onsurface (TextureView) an image , but how i do to integrate this part:

"PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height);
                    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

                    rawResult = mQrReader.decode(bitmap);
                    onQRCodeRead(rawResult.getText());
"
Can I get back to the image data structure in this way?

Comment: Oh, ignore that part, sorry. You don't need a PlanarYuvLuminance, nor a Binary Bitmap. You need to use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()

Comment: How load in b the data? 

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

bytes = data?

Comment: Yeah, totally :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please, mark this answer as acepted if i helped you